# FOX pro undo - redo

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Is there an undo/redo function on Visual Fox pro?

I have been using the previous version whenever I screw up, but I wondering if there was a way to do it from the command window

or is there a program for it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about undoing changes made in a table? You're going to want to set buffers on your table before making any changes. I would suggest opening the FoxPro help file (Menu > Help) and search for "Buffering Data". That will give a thorough explanation of what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Once you save changes there is no way to 'UnDo' the changes in FoxPro.

Use source control. Then you can check out the current version, make changes, test it, and if it doesn't work, get the latest code again.

Comment: If you are referring to source control then you should take a look at [FoxBin2Prg](https://github.com/fdbozzo/foxbin2prg) which converts to and from a Text format which is extremely similar to actual VFP syntax, making it easy to read, diff, and merge.

Comment: FoxBin2Prg is definitely recommend when using source control as the db files that store code for forms, classes, projects, etc... are easily corruptible.